# Joomla: How to set unique permalink on K2?

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I have different tags in K2. When I use some of them for an item, I get duplicate content:

URL1: site.com/category1/tag2/ (If I access the item from a tag2 menu filtered by category1)

URL2: site.com/category1/tag4/ (If I access the item from a tag4 menu filtered by category1)

Both URLs load the same content. How can I set a unique URL that can be accessed from the same menus?

Thank you

---

Solved:

Solved following these steps:

http://getk2.org/blog/1159-k2-v264-release-introduces-new-cool-sef-url-options

What I meant by "unique URL" is that an item needs to "have" only one URL (as Wordpress does). Example:

site.com/category/title-of-the-article

With K2, you can access the same item from different URLs, if you have menus with tags.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "How can I set a unique URL that can be accessed from the same menus?"

Answer (score 0):

Solved following these steps:

http://getk2.org/blog/1159-k2-v264-release-introduces-new-cool-sef-url-options

What I meant by "unique URL" is that an item needs to "have" only one URL (as Wordpress does). Example:

site.com/category/title-of-the-article

With K2, you can access the same item from different URLs, if you have menus with tags.